# Symfony2: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::getResult()

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

With the code:

```
$qb = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$qb->select('cat')->from('BuyAndSellSiteBundle:Category ', 'cat');
$qb->getQuery();
$a =$qb->getResult();
```

I get an exception:

```
FatalErrorException: Error: Call to undefined method Doctrine\ORM\QueryBuilder::getResult() in C:\xampp\htdocs\buySell\src\BuyAndSell\SiteBundle\Controller\DefaultController.php line
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This makes sense. Because `QueryBuilder` does not change itself, you need to store result of `getQuery()` invocation :

```
$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('cat')->from('BuyAndSellSiteBundle:Category ', 'cat');

// get the Query from the QueryBuilder here ...
$query = $qb->getQuery();

// ... then call getResult() on the Query (not on the QueryBuilder)
$result = $query->getResult();
```

Comment: correct answer! the `QueryBuilder` doesn't have a `getResult()` method .. only the `Query` instance that can be obtained by invoking the `getQuery()` method on a `QueryBuilder` object provides this method. `$qb` is an instance of **Q** uery **B** uilder here. I edited your answer's variable names to make it more obvious :)

Comment: This isn't working for me.  I get `Call to undefined method Doctrine\DBAL\Query\QueryBuilder::getQuery()`

Comment: You probably have a wrong import on the top as `QueryBuilder` belongs to `Doctrine\ORM` namespace and not to `DBAL`'s.

Comment: `DBAL`'s `QueryBuilder` is a whole another different thing :) See: http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/dbal/2.5/class-Doctrine.DBAL.Query.QueryBuilder.html

Answer (score 4):

Change to:

```
$a = $qb->getQuery()->getResult();

// or

$q = $qb->getQuery();
$a = $q->getResult();
```